# What's the point of "but" in some sentences?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

From [The Godfather](http://parrain.narod.ru/):

> And so it was Fanucci alone. Or Fannucci with some gunmen hired for a
>   special job on a strictly cash basis. Which left Vito Corleone with
>   another decision. The course his own life must take.
>
> It was from this experience came his oft-repeated belief that every man
>   has ***but*** one desteny.

I expected that ***only*** would have been instead of ***but*** there. Therefore I'd like to ask the reason for using ***but*** in that sentence.

Answer (score 5):

> ***But***: *adv* formal only; just - [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/but)

Examples:

> I was considered but a nuisance to the team.
>
> [What was I but a glimpse of time?](http://www.anti.com/releases/may/tracks/glimpse-of-a-time/)

Answer (score 5):

This use of *but* in the sense “merely, only” rests on ellipsis of a prior negative:

> I have <s>no life</s> but one life to give for my country.
>   Every man has <s>none</s> but one destiny.

It's been around in English for a very long time, but began to fade in the 19th century; today it has an oldfashioned, literary ring. Note that this is characteristic of Don Vito’s speech and thoughts: it reflects both his non-native command of English and his devotion to archaic, almost chivalric notions of community and honour.

Comment: I never read *The Godfather*, but I was struck by the rather neat clipped "Hemmingwayesque" style, which nicely reflects Vito's slow methodical "one thing at a time" way of thinking (and which I know from the movies). But I couldn't help thinking the transition from the first to the second sentence looked comparatively clunky. So I found a copy of the original, and was gratified to discover OP had missed out the word ***alone***. I like your point about the old-fashioned usage reflecting Vito's stance re things like family, community, honour.